# questions repeated 4x, float not callable, error on code

Tags: python, floating-point

I dont understand why the code doesnt work and they have repeated the questions to me 4 times. and say that float is not callable. i have tried doing this for quite awhile but i dont seem to get anything at all. is there any easier way for python3? I just learnt this language 2 weeks ago. its not a whole new world to me but many of the things i am not familiar with. such as indentation

```
def get_taxi_info():
        flag_down = float(input("What's the flag-down fare: $"))
        within = float(input("What's the rate per 400 meters within 9.8km? $"))
        beyond = float(input("What's the rate per 350 meters beyond 9.8km? $"))
        distance = float(input("What's the distance traveled (in meters)? "))
        peak = input("Is the ride during a peak period? [yes/no]")
        mid6 = input("Is the ride between midnight and 6am? [yes/no]")
        location = input("Is there any location surcharge? [yes/no]")
        surloca = float(input("What's the amount of location surcharge?"))
        return (flag_down, within, beyond, distance, peak == 'yes', mid6 == 'yes', location == 'yes', surloca)

    def calculate_taxi_fare():
        dist = get_taxi_info()
        if dist[3] > 9800:
            extra = (dist[3] - 9800) % 350
            if extra == 0:
                a = (extra//350) + 22
            else:
                a = (extra//350) + 23
            return a
        elif dist[3] <= 9800:
            extra = (dist[3] - 1000) % 400
            if extra == 0:
                a = (extra//400)
            else:
                a = (extra//400) + 1
            return a

    def peakornot():
        peak = get_taxi_info()
        if peak[4] == True and peak[5] == False:
            surcharge = 1.25
            return surcharge
        elif peak[4] == False and peak[5] == True:
            surcharge = 1.50
            return surcharge

    taxifare = calculate_taxi_fare()
    info = get_taxi_info()
    peak1 = peakornot()
    taxifare = calculate_taxi_fare()
    if info[6] == True:
        payable = ((info[0] + (info[1] * taxifare()) + (info[2] * taxifare())) * peak1[0]) + info[7]
        print ("The total fare is $" + str(payable))
    elif info[6] == False:
        payable = ((info[0] + (info[1] * taxifare()) + (info[2] * taxifare())) * peak1[0]) + info[7]
        print ("The total fare is $" + str(payable))
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `calculate_taxi_fare` returns a `float`, so on this line `taxifare` is a `float`

```
taxifare = calculate_taxi_fare()
```

Therefore you cannot say `taxifare()` because it looks like a function call, so you can just use for example

```
info[1] * taxifare
```

Comment: after i tried doing that it returns. TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. and it still question me 4 repeated times